# Starting and ending point to images

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to set a starting and ending point to images. So I have my canvas and my images, when I drop my images into the canvas I want that when I hover at the starting/ending point it lights a little red circle which means that I can create a connection with other images. For example: **1) Drag the image. 2) Drop the image inside the canvas. 3) Hover to the starting/ending point, and it lights up in a little red dot.**
[image: As you can see, the red dots that only appear on hover]

As you can see, the red dots that only appear on hover. Another problem, but if you fix the first one is cool, the images don't follow the grill (squares).
Here is an example of html/js

```js
const resistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_resistor');
const condensator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_condensator');
const tranistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_tranistor');
const alimentator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_alimentator');
const circuit = document.getElementById('components_circuit');
const back_button = document.getElementById('back-button');
const clear_button = document.getElementById('clear-button');
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const foward_button = document.getElementById('foward-button');


/** EDIT START */
const draggableImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[draggable]');

for (let i = 0; i < draggableImages.length; i++)
  draggableImages[i].ondragstart = (ev) => {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', i.toString());
  };

canvas.ondragover = (ev) => ev.preventDefault(); // IMPORTANT

const orderStack = [];
const deletedOrderStack = [];

const drawnImageData = [];
const deletedImageData = [];

canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
  const index = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  const img = draggableImages[index];
  const x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft - img.width / 2;
  const y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop - img.height / 2;
  const squareSize = 10; // adjust this to match the size of your squares
  const maxSize = 75; // maximum size of the image
  const aspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
  let width = maxSize;
  let height = maxSize / aspectRatio;
  if (height > maxSize) {
    height = maxSize;
    width = height * aspectRatio;
  }
  const snappedX = Math.round(x / squareSize) * squareSize;
  const snappedY = Math.round(y / squareSize) * squareSize;
  ctx.drawImage(img, snappedX, snappedY, width, height);
  drawnImageData.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
  orderStack.push(1);
  deletedImageData.length = 0;
  deletedOrderStack.length = 0;
  back_button.disabled = false;
  back_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  clear_button.disabled = false;
  clear_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  foward_button.disabled = true;
  foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  return false;
};

clear_button.disabled = true;
clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
foward_button.disabled = true;
foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
back_button.disabled = true;
back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
/** EDIT END */

canvas.width = 1900;

canvas.height = 1000;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
circuit.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.borderRadius = '10px';
canvas.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
canvas.style.marginRight = 'auto';
canvas.style.display = 'block';
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//const circles = [];
const lines = [];
const lines_c = [];
var deletedLines = [];

function drawSquares() {
  const squareSize = 10;
  const numColumns = Math.floor(canvas.width / squareSize);
  const numRows = Math.floor(canvas.height / squareSize);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF9F9";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#F4F1F0";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
      const x = i * squareSize;
      const y = j * squareSize;

      if (i % 10 === 0 && j % 10 === 0) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 2.6;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#F1ECEB";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#E6E0DE"; // set the stroke color to a darker shade
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, squareSize * 10, squareSize * 10);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#F4F1F0";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#F4F1F0"; // reset the stroke color
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      } else {
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, squareSize, squareSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

drawSquares();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- <title>From Circuit to Breadboard</title> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="components">
            <div id="components_circuit">
                <h3 id ="h3_componenti_circuit">Componenti:</h3>
                    <ul id="components_circuit_border">
                        <li><img id ="component_circuit_resistor" src="https://www.elprocus.com/wp-content/uploads/Resistor-Symbol-768x288.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id = "component_circuit_condensator" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Capacitor_Symbol_alternative.svg/1280px-Capacitor_Symbol_alternative.svg.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id="component_circuit_transistor" src="images/circuit_transistor.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id="component_circuit_alimentator" src="images/circuit_alimentator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                    </ul>
                <div class = "elementi_disegno">
                    <h1 id ="h1_disegna">Disegna il tuo circuito!</h1>
                <button id="back-button">Indietro
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">undo</span>
                </button>
                <button id="foward-button">Avanti
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">redo</span>
                </button>
                <button id="clear-button">Clear All
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
                </button>
                <canvas id = "canvas" class = "dropzone"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code provided, maybe that doesn't work on stackoverflow, try it locally. And if you use other images please provide the link.

Comment: You sould use svgs if you want to control elements. Create an svg for capacitor and resistor and add another circle to the end points of them. then create an algorithm to change the fill of the circles to red if your cursor is close enough.

Comment: Have you looked into using some libraries like http://fabricjs.com/ is that something you will consider?

Comment: I've never heard about fabricjs but yes I would consider it if that can fix my problem. I'll do some researches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can keep track of the x and y of the images in an array and iterate through the array to check if the mouse pointer is a certain distance from any object and if so draw a circle, In the remote images the connections are at the half way point in both sides if you are planning to add more than the 2 images that show up (Idk about the images that are hosted locally) with different start and end point you will need to change the values depending on the image however with the current setup you can just hard code it, here is my implementation:

```
const resistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_resistor');
const condensator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_condensator');
const tranistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_tranistor');
const alimentator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_alimentator');
const circuit = document.getElementById('components_circuit');
const back_button = document.getElementById('back-button');
const clear_button = document.getElementById('clear-button');
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const foward_button = document.getElementById('foward-button');
let images = [];

/** EDIT START */
const draggableImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[draggable]');

for (let i = 0; i < draggableImages.length; i++)
  draggableImages[i].ondragstart = (ev) => {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', i.toString());
  };

canvas.ondragover = (ev) => ev.preventDefault(); // IMPORTANT

const orderStack = [];
const deletedOrderStack = [];

const drawnImageData = [];
const deletedImageData = [];
canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
    
    const index = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
    const img = draggableImages[index];
    const x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft - img.width / 2;
    const y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop - img.height / 2;
    const squareSize = 10; // adjust this to match the size of your squares


    const maxSize = 75; // maximum size of the image
    const aspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
    let width = maxSize;
    let height = maxSize / aspectRatio;
    if (height > maxSize) {
      height = maxSize;
      width = height * aspectRatio;
    }
    const snappedX = Math.round(x / squareSize) * squareSize;
    const snappedY = Math.round(y / squareSize) * squareSize;
    ctx.drawImage(img, snappedX, snappedY, width, height);
    images.push({ img, x: snappedX, y: snappedY, width, height });
    // Add the image and its position to the images array

  };
  

  
 
clear_button.disabled = true;
clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
foward_button.disabled = true;
foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
back_button.disabled = true;
back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
/** EDIT END */

canvas.width = 1900;

canvas.height = 1000;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
circuit.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.borderRadius = '10px';
canvas.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
canvas.style.marginRight = 'auto';
canvas.style.display = 'block';
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//const circles = [];
const lines = [];
const lines_c = [];
var deletedLines = [];

function drawSquares() {
  const squareSize = 10;
  const numColumns = Math.floor(canvas.width / squareSize);
  const numRows = Math.floor(canvas.height / squareSize);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF9F9";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#F4F1F0";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
      const x = i * squareSize;
      const y = j * squareSize;

      if (i % 10 === 0 && j % 10 === 0) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 2.6;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#F1ECEB";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#E6E0DE"; // set the stroke color to a darker shade
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, squareSize * 10, squareSize * 10);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#F4F1F0";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#F4F1F0"; // reset the stroke color
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      } else {
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, squareSize, squareSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

drawSquares();

// Add a mousemove event to the canvas to show the red dot
  const redDotRadius = 5; // The radius of the red dots
  const hoverDistance = 10; // The distance from a point at which to show the dot

canvas.onmousemove = (ev) => {
    const mouseX = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    const mouseY = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    
    // Clear the canvas and redraw everything
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawSquares();
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      let image = images[i];
      ctx.drawImage(image.img, image.x, image.y, image.width, image.height);
    }
    
    // Check if the mouse is near a starting or ending point
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      let image = images[i];
      let startX = image.x+5;
      let startY = image.y + image.height/2;
      let endX = image.x + image.width -5;
      let endY = image.y + image.height/2;
      
      if (Math.abs(mouseX - startX) < hoverDistance && Math.abs(mouseY - startY) < hoverDistance) {
        // Near the starting point, draw a red dot
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(startX, startY, redDotRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();
      } else if (Math.abs(mouseX - endX) < hoverDistance && Math.abs(mouseY - endY) < hoverDistance) {
        // Near the ending point, draw a red dot
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(endX, endY, redDotRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }
  };
```

I didn't change the html

Comment: It kinda works but is really bugged.

Comment: @SkerdiVelo I hate to say the criminal phrase but it works perfectly fine in my machine, could you provide more details on how its bugged? do you mean that its too precise for the hover effect to appear? increasing the hoverDistance const will make the hover Radius bigger and less precise

Comment: It is not precise and if I change the resolution of google chrome(ctrl +) it doesn't work. The dots are not an element attached to the image. Later with the dots I'll need to draw a connection with other images, so it has to be precise. I'll wait for some other answers, still give you an upvote. If someone else doesn't respond, I'll give you the bounty

Comment: @SkerdiVelo this is a good implementation ... in your code you did not even attempted to code the `onmousemove`, that is likely why no one took the time to answer before you added a bounty ... and yes there are many other factors like resolution or zoom that might introduce bugs... you are adding more requirements to your question in the comments "the dots need to draw a connection with other images" you need to focus your questions into one small problem at a time, questions with hundred of lines of code are quite often ignored

Comment: @Decod621 to improve your answer you should explain what you are doing inside the onmousemove function